# How to edit existing Azure storage account CORS Rule through Bash Script

Tags: bash, azure-devops, devops, azure-storage-account

I've been working as Devops engineer from past 3 months. So, I am learning creating scripts for automation. But I am stuck here.
I wanna try to edit the CORS rule through bash script. I have successfully written a script for adding the rule but every time i run the script, its create a new rule. I want to edit the existing rule.

Here's the script line, I am using to add CORS rule.

```
Add_Rule=$(az storage cors add --account-name testingscriptcors --origins 'http://google321.comh, http://www.google123.com'  --methods GET PUT --allowed-headers '*' --exposed-headers '*' --max-age 200 --services b)
```

What I am thinking that if I provide ( --rule 1  ) in this script, It'll worked out. But this doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can add and edit the existing rule using `Set-AzStorageCORSRule`. You can approch this way as i have mentioned here.**

***Cmdlet to Set or add the CORS rule***

```
$ctx=New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName "clouXXXXXXXman" -StorageAccountKey "ExXXXXXXXXXzUgkXi80HHrXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
$CorsRules = (@{
AllowedHeaders=@("x-ms-blob-content-type","x-ms-blob-content-disposition");
AllowedOrigins=@("*");
MaxAgeInSeconds=30;
AllowedMethods=@("Get","Connect")},
@{
AllowedOrigins=@("http://www.fabrikam.com","http://www.contoso.com");
ExposedHeaders=@("x-ms-meta-data*","x-ms-meta-customheader");
AllowedHeaders=@("x-ms-meta-target*","x-ms-meta-customheader");
MaxAgeInSeconds=30;
AllowedMethods=@("Put")})
Set-AzStorageCORSRule -ServiceType Blob -CorsRules $CorsRules -Context $ctx
```

***Once Set you can check the list of rule using below command***

```
az storage cors list --account-name cloudXXXXXXn --account-key ExlYLcXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

[image]

***Change properties of a CORS rule for blob service***

```
$ctx1=New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName "cloXXXXXuman" -StorageAccountKey "ExlYLc5XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
$CorsRules = Get-AzStorageCORSRule -ServiceType Blob -Context $ctx1
$CorsRules[0].AllowedHeaders = @("x-ms-blob-content-type", "x-ms-blob-content-disposition")
$CorsRules[0].AllowedMethods = @("Get", "Connect", "Merge")
Set-AzStorageCORSRule -ServiceType Blob -CorsRules $CorsRules -Context $ctx1
```

[image]

You can refer this [***MS Document***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.storage/set-azstoragecorsrule?view=azps-7.2.0#parameters) for more information.

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked out, But can you please let me know how to do it in .sh (bash script)

Comment: Sure will try and get back to you.

Comment: Hey, you find something?

Comment: Sorry, i could not try it out yet. Allow me time by tommrow. I will test it and update the answer if i will find it.

Comment: Tried but not sure how it should be in bash script, You can refer this link[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/use-cli-effectively#pass-arguments] it may help you to convert the above Powershell CLI command to bash.

Comment: Nope, Nope. I have searched alot. I guess we cannot do this in bash script. as We cannot clear any single cor rule, or edit cor rule.

Comment: Yes, I am thiking same.since the Module is for AZ PowerShell not for Bash.